# How to mount an antique cast iron sink

Tags: sink, installation

I have a vintage Kohler cast iron sink that I want to mount outside to use as a beverage station. It has legs and bolting points on the back (see picture). I am hoping to bolt it directly to the brick exterior of my home. The contractor can't quite figure out the best way to do this. It appears that it has brackets along the top back that can slide/sit in a wall mount but I don't have those wall mounts. Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: So what is holding it against the wall now?  Other similar sinks I've seen have metal brackets that you attach to the wall and then this will hook over the top of those brackets.  How about a photo of the backside of this?

Comment: A few pictures of the back and underneath would be helpful.

Comment: Cool looking sink but rather shallow.

Comment: you could also put it on top of a cabinet

Comment: If you are removing it from that location then the mounts must be there.

Answer (score 1):

Buy some wall mounts. You should be able to find new or used (Salvage yard, Ebay, Hardware store) mounts that will work. Most are just an angled piece of cast iron or steel that the sink hangs on. Since your sink has legs most of the weight will be on the legs and the wall brackets will keep it from falling forward. [image: New Brackets]

[image: Used Bracket]

Comment: You could probably make a couple of these if necessary. A bit of flat bar stock - drill a couple of holes. Grip in a vice and knock a bend into it with a hammer. It may take a bit of practice/trial-n-error to get it right, but that's how things were done when this sink was new, so it'll fit right in the the vibe...

Comment: @PlatinumGoose, a bit more than 1/2 of the weight is on the legs, the rest is on the brackets

Comment: I would say more than half of the weight is on the brackets, since that backsplash area looks bigger than the front apron...